# SFTP connector in Azure Logic App throws error : The maximum number of requests allowed '1000' was not sufficient to upload the entire content

Tags: azure, sftp, azure-logic-apps

While testing out the SFTP connector in Azure Logic App for dropping a file to SFTP location, i am getting this error :

```
The maximum number of requests allowed '1000' was not sufficient to upload the entire content. Uploaded content length: '253'.
```

The partially uploaded file can be seen at the sftp location. Whereas there are no issues when using Filezilla. I am trying to push an XML file with a file size of approximately 3KB.

I didn't find any other configuration to be done on Logic Apps designer. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked when Chunking was disabled in the settings.